# When are function arguments copied?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdmove

I am interested to know when the arguments of a function are copied.

```
#include <vector>

void foo (std::vector<float> a)
{
   std::vector<float> y = std::move(a);
   //do something with vector y
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<float> x {1.0f, 2.0f, 3.0f};
   std::cout << x.at(0) << " " << x.at(1) << " " << x.at(2) << std::endl; //1.0 2.0 3.0
   foo(x);
   std::cout << x.at(0) << " " << x.at(1) << " " << x.at(2) << std::endl; //print nothing
}
```

Does the function copy its argument from the start? If not, how do we know when the arguments are copied? From the above code, I assume that the arguments are not copied because std::move still affects variable x.

Comment: `//print nothing` -- No, this is not correct. I'm not sure how you are running this, but [when I run it, `x` is not changed](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d88915cdbac670ac).

Answer (score 3):

> Does the function copy its argument from the start?

The `a` argument is copied at the call site within `main()`, before the body of `foo()` is entered.

> From the above code, I assume that the arguments are not copied because std::move still affects variable `x`.

The `a` argument is being passed *by value*, so `a` makes a *copy* of `x`.  Then `foo()` `move`'s the *copy* into `y`.  `x` is un-affected, which is the opposite of your claim.

If the `a` argument were passed *by reference* instead, or you `move`'d `x` into `a`, then `x` would be affected.